# NSException when using Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I followed all the steps correctly to install Firebase to my iOS App and it still doesn't work. In the application method, I added `FIRApp.configure()` like so:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FIRApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

And I keep receiving `NSException` errors. Firebase seems to work on my Android Project, what's the deal with iOS?

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: This won't help me because the exception occurred at the declaration of the AppDelegate class and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is some sort of Swift 3 issue, because I encountered a similar problem. After looking over the internet, I believe that Firebase 3 hasn't updated to recent Swift Syntax located in Swift 3. Many other developers are having trouble with it as well. As an alternative, you could switch back from Xcode 8 and into 7, which would allow you to create your application which will work with current IOS, and when Firebase updates, it will be easy for you to migrate to Swift 3.

Hope this helps, 
Morgan Gallant

Comment: I'll try this out, but can I run Xcode 8 apps on Xcode 7? Have you tried this out?

Comment: I don't think so unfortunately, because it would have to downgrade the Swift Syntax. I haven't tried it myself, but It would be interesting to give it a shot. As I said before, making a project in Xcode 7 and then migrating will be very easy, due to Xcode's useful code migration tools. I think this is the best way to go, especially before you get to into your Swift 3 Xcode 8 project.

Comment: I tried using Xcode 7 and followed all the steps but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Never mind, I'm not sure what I did wrong but I got it working. I guess Swift 2 does work. Thanks!